# Empty String Returned from Tkinter Text

Tags: tkinter

I'm having this issue where my retrieveInputForTextFile function works as intended retrieving the input from the Text, but another similar function (retrieveInputForGlobalVars) just returns an empty string when I'm trying to print it with print(someValue). Is there something I'm overlooking? It does reach my function because "This button has been pressed!" prints out fine.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

style = ttk.Style()

root = Tk()
# root.withdraw() # Remove additional, blank window
root.title("aaaaaa")
# asksaveasfilename()

# GLOBAL VARIABLES
CELL_COL = "filler"
GOOGLE_SHEETS_FILENAME = "filler"
POINTS = "filler"


try:
    fp = open("input.txt", "w")
except:
    print("File to open does not exist!")

def retrieveInputForTextFile():
    inputValue = textBox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    fp.write(inputValue)
    print(inputValue)

############ DEBUGING ##############

def retrieveInputForGlobalVars():
    someValue = spreadSheetTextBox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(someValue)
    print("This button has been pressed!")
    global GOOGLE_SHEETS_FILENAME
    GOOGLE_SHEETS_FILENAME = someValue
    #print(globalVarName)

############ DEBUGING ##############


# Defining the global style (applied when no other style is defined)
style.configure('.', font='Arial 14', foreground='brown', background='black')
############ DEBUGING ##############
ttk.Label(root, text="What is the spreadsheet name?:").pack()
spreadSheetTextBox = Text(root, height=1, width=50)
spreadSheetTextBox.pack()

enterButton = ttk.Button(root, text='Enter', command=retrieveInputForGlobalVars)
enterButton.pack()
############ DEBUGING ##############

ttk.Label(root, text="Which column are we modifying?:").pack()
spreadSheetTextBox = Text(root, height=1, width=2)
spreadSheetTextBox.pack()

ttk.Label(root, text="How many points do you want to input:").pack()
spreadSheetTextBox = Text(root, height=1, width=2)
spreadSheetTextBox.pack()

### WORKING CODE ###
ttk.Label(root, text="Please input names of members who attended this meeting:").pack()
textBox = Text(root, height=30, width=20)
textBox.pack()
# Button Widget
submitButton = ttk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=retrieveInputForTextFile)
submitButton.pack()
# Defining a new style named danger
style.configure('danger.TButton', font='Times 12', foreground='red', padding=1)

root.mainloop()
fp.close()
root.destroy()
```

Comment: You've defined more than one widget as `spreadSheetTextBox` How is the code supposed to know which one you want to use?

Comment: Oh I didn't see that! Thank you so much that solved my problem!